# How to handle FUSE root directory permissions?

Tags: c, file-permissions, fuse

I'm implementing a FUSE filesystem as an exercise. In my `init` callback I set up a struct for the root directory, using the UID/GID given by the FUSE context:

```
struct fuse_context* context = fuse_get_context();
root->stat.st_uid = context->uid;
root->stat.st_gid = context->gid;
```

But the problem is that these values are always 0 i.e. root ownership. So if I mount it as a normal user, I can't do anything with it. By default FUSE does not allow the root user to touch a FUSE-mounted file system (for security reasons, I think), so I can't even use `sudo` to create files in it. Everything works fine if I mount it with

```
sudo ./myfs mnt -o allow_other
```

because then I can do something like

```
sudo mkdir mnt/mydir
sudo chown max:users mnt/mydir
```

and do everything in `mnt/mydir` as a regular user. But what is the proper way to set up a FUSE file system so that the root is owned by the current user?

I tried running with

```
./myfs mnt -o uid=1000 -o gid=100
```

but that only makes it *look* like root is owned by me. I still get permission errors and looking in GDB I see that as before UID=GID=0 in `init`.

Comment: Probably i may got wrong, but are you sure that zeros in fuse_context is means root ownership and not just indicate that there is no context available? fuse-context is a context of a specific call from the kernel, and available only within such call.

Comment: Ah, so am I supposed to mount it with a regular `mount` call so that the kernel sets it up or something? I haven't seen anything about needing to do that...

Comment: "The context is only valid for the duration of a filesystem operation, and thus must not be stored and used later."
I mean you may use get_context incorrect